# How to write the 2 different results in one excel sheet using java for selenium webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium

The scenario is First I execute the one result and create the excel and update in it.Now again I execute the second result and trying to update in the same sheet of different rows but I dint get both the result in one sheet. It shows only the second result.

```
     FileOutputStream exlFileName= new FileOutputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\testExcel.xls");
     WritableWorkbook exlWorkBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFileName);
     WritableSheet exlWorkSheet1 = exlWorkBook.createSheet("Preload data check",0);
     Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent1 = new Label(1,0,"FIRST NAME",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent2 = new Label(2,0,"DOB",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent3 = new Label(3,0,"GENDER",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent4 = new Label(4,0,"ADMIT DATE AND TIME",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent5 = new Label(5,0,"PROVIDER NAME",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent6 = new Label(6,0,"BILL TYPE",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent7 = new Label(7,0,"DOS DATE AND TIME",cellFormat);
     Label Sheet1cellContent8 = new Label(8,0,"SCREENSHOT",cellFormat);

     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent1);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent2);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent3);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent4);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent5);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent6);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent7);
     exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent8);
```

This is the first result I will get with some values now I write code for 2nd result.

```
 FileOutputStream exlFileName= new FileOutputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\testExcel.xls");   
 WritableWorkbook exlWorkBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFileName); 
 WritableSheet exlWorkSheet1 = exlWorkBook.createSheet("Preload data check",0); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent10 = new Label(1,5,"CPT Description",cellFormat);
 Label Sheet1cellContent12 = new Label(2,5,"Modifier1",cellFormat);
 Label Sheet1cellContent13 = new Label(3,5,"Modifier2",cellFormat); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent14 = new Label(4,5,"ICD1",cellFormat);
 Label Sheet1cellContent15 = new Label(5,5,"ICD2",cellFormat); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent16 = new Label(6,5,"Dx Notes",cellFormat); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent17 = new Label(7,5,"DOS date",cellFormat); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent18 = new Label(8,5,"Provider name",cellFormat); 
 Label Sheet1cellContent19 = new Label(9,5,"Screenshot",cellFormat);            
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent9);
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent10);
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent12); 
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent13);
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent14); 
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent15);
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent16); 
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent17); 
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent18); 
 exlWorkSheet1.addCell(Sheet1cellContent19);
```

### Kindly help me out of this.

Comment: One suggestion i can make, is be consistent with your coding style.  You go from camelCase to PascalCase. Choose one, and stick with it.  My recommendation is stick to camelCase as it's Java's standard.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than always creating the workbook and sheet, try to see if the workbook or sheet already exists. If it exists open it in edit mode and add the new result set.